# Suppose that the measurable sets $A_{1},A_{2}, ..... $ are ''almost disjoint'' in the sense that $\lambda( A_{j} \cap A_{k} )=0$ if $j \neq k$.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose that the measurable sets $A_{1},A_{2}, ..... $ are ''almost disjoint'' in the sense that $\lambda( A_{j}  \cap A_{k} )=0$ if $j \neq k$. Prove that 
\begin{equation}
 \lambda (\cup_{k=1}^{\infty} A_{k}) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \lambda(A_{k})
\end{equation}
Hint: Note that one of the inequalities is tirivial and to show the other e realize each $(A_{k}$ can be expressed as $(A_{k}= I_{k} \cup (A_{k} \setminus I_{k}))$  where $I_{k} = \cup A_{j}  \cap A_{k} $ where $j \neq k$.

Comment: What have you tried yourself?

Comment: Maybe replace $A_k$ by $A_k'$ where the $A_k'$ **are** disjoint and then...

Comment: Can you get the $\leq$ direction?

Answer (score 2):

**Hints**: note that $A_k=I_k\sqcup (A_k\setminus I_k)$ is a disjoint union, so $$\lambda(A_k)=\lambda(I_k)+\lambda(A_k\setminus I_k).$$ Then $\sqcup_{k\geq 1} (A_k\setminus I_k)$ is a disjoint union, i.e. the sets $A_k\setminus I_k$ are pairwise disjoint, so we can write $$\lambda\left(\bigsqcup_{k\geq 1} A_k\setminus I_k\right)=\sum_{k\geq 1} \lambda(A_k\setminus I_k).$$ What do we know about $\lambda(I_k)$?

Comment: I am frightened by the boxy union symbol thingy.

Comment: @Michael haha, yes it is a little intimidating I suppose. Just used to express the fact that the union is disjoint.